# Make element stick to top when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a function to make a div element stick to top when scrolling.

it works when it's written like this('#sticky-anchor-for-social' is to detect moving distance of the element, '#social-media' is the element sticks):

```
function sticky_socialmedia() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var social_top = $('#sticky-anchor-for-social').offset().top - 88;
    if (window_top >= social_top) {
       $('#social-media').addClass('stick-social');
    } else {
       $('#social-media').removeClass('stick-social');
    }
}

$(window).scroll(sticky_socialmedia);
sticky_socialmedia();
```

but it doesn't work when I write it like this:

```
function stickyWhenScroll(anchor, sticky) {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var filter_top = $(anchor).offset().top - 88;
    if (window_top >= filter_top) {
       $(sticky).addClass('stick-filter');
    } else {
       $(sticky).removeClass('stick-filter');
    }
 }

 $(window).scroll(stickyWhenScroll);
 stickyWhenScroll('#sticky-anchor-for-social','#social-media');
```

what could possibly go wrong?
many thanks!

Comment: Because the event gets trigger when you scroll. In your first attempt you make a reference to your elements inside the function, but the second attempt you are not referencing inside but are trying to do it outside which, in this way, doesn't work\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your parameters to your function when adding the event, you can do that with [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$(window).bind('scroll', {
    anchor: '#sticky-anchor-for-social', 
    sticky: '#social-media'
}, stickyWhenScroll).trigger('scroll');
```

By passing `trigger('scroll')` you can trigger the function straight away.

And in your function you can retrieve them by accesing the `event.data`:

```
function stickyWhenScroll(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    var anchor = data.anchor;
    var sticky = data.sticky;
    ...
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad6fojf7/1)

Comment: thanks! It works nicely as well! But same with the other answer, the reason I want to use the 2nd snippet is that I have two elements both need to stick to the top in different pages, so I want to write a function then pass them different params to make both work, is there any ways to make it happen?

Comment: You can have the function on both pages but reference difference elements, or just call the elements the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Because in your 2nd snippet the scroll event handler hasn't received any params. You could either pass params both times (load and scroll) or declare those as global variables and use them within the function.

```
(function stickyWhenScroll(anchor, sticky) {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var filter_top = $(anchor).offset().top - 88;
    if (window_top >= filter_top) {
        $(sticky).addClass('stick-filter');
    } else {
        $(sticky).removeClass('stick-filter');
    }
}('#sticky-anchor-for-social', '#social-media'));

$(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyWhenScroll('#sticky-anchor-for-social','#social-media');
});
```

Comment: thanks! It works. But the reason I want to use the 2nd snippet is that I have two elements both need to stick to the top in different pages, so I want to write a function then pass them different params to make both work. but the answers don't seem to achieve that, how should I do?